# SRV record to use subdomain to portforward to main domain

Tags: dns

Using GoDaddy, you are able to setup a SRV record

```
dig any _http._tcp.tvlight.xahnet.com                                                                                                                                        

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> any _http._tcp.tvlight.xahnet.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 8618
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;_http._tcp.tvlight.xahnet.com. IN  ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
_http._tcp.tvlight.xahnet.com. 2392 IN  SRV 0 5 5000 xahnet.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
xahnet.com.     297 IN  A   169.239.209.40

;; Query time: 583 msec
;; SERVER: 172.18.16.44#53(172.18.16.44)
;; WHEN: Wed May  3 14:54:14 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 93
```

but i am unable to figure out how to get http://tvlight.xahnet.com to work
it keeps telling me:

```
** server can't find tvlight.xahnet.com: NXDOMAIN
```

when i try to curl to it or ping it or anything.

Hopefully someone will have a better idea of what is going on and if you need more information let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers are basically ignoring `SRV` record, they will just connect on port 80 or 443 of the hostname you provide in the URL.

`tvlight.xahnet.com` currently has no A nor AAAA records, hence a browser can not connect to it.

Comment: i have added an A record for tvlight.xahnet.com but it still doesn't forward to port 5000. http://tvlight.xahnet.com/state should return some json state but it still doesn't work

Comment: The DNS does not "forward". You put an A record, and then the browser will contact port 80 or 443 as stated above. You then need to have something there that will do the redirections you need. Indeed right now there seems to be nothing listening on port 80 for the IP address of `tvlight.xahnet.com/state`. But if you use `http://tvlight.xahnet.com:5000/state` it works.

Comment: The SRV records do work! It is just that browsers are **not** using them at all!